# How to access multiple levels of overridden elements?

Tags: c++, scope, multiple-inheritance

How do I access overridden members of base classes of base classes?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {public: char x; A(){x='A';};};
class B1 : public A {public: char x; B1(){x='B';};};
class B2 : public A {public: char x; B2(){x='B';};};
class C : public B1, public B2 {public: char x; C(){x='C';};};

int main(){
    C c;
    cout << c.x << endl; // prints C

    cout << c.B1::x << endl; // prints B
    cout << ((B1&) c).x << endl; // prints B

    // cout << c.A::x << endl; // normally prints A but doesn't work here
    cout << ((A&) c).x << endl; // prints A
    return 0;
}
```

Is the reference (or pointer) way the only possibility?
I tried A::B::x in order to chain scope operators, but that doesn't work.
Suppose i want to keep the "double A", i.e. not make the inheritance virtual.

`((B&) c).x` seems to be a good "workaround" to `c.B::x` but they aren't equal in case of virtual functions, are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access both version of A via reference casts plus the scoping operator, likes this: `((B1&) c).A::x` and `((B2&) c).A::x`.

`cout << ((A&) c).x << endl;` fails on my compiler because the compiler doesn't know which copy of A's data you want to operate on.

Comment: Good - combining reference cast and scope op seems to be solving all problems. I'll accept that if no one comes up with another problem ...

Answer (score 1):

```
c.A::x
```

Comment: Yeah ok...
The problem came up with multiple inheritance... I thought it could be simplified by just multiple levels of inheritance but in fact the problem vanishes than. thx for pointing that out :-)
- op edited

Answer (score 0):

It won't work and the compiler should tell you why. At least mine does :-) : "A ambigous base for C". The answer is **virtual inheritance**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {public: char x; A(){x='A';};};
class B1 : public virtual A {public: char x; B1(){x='B';};};
class B2 : public virtual A {public: char x; B2(){x='B';};};
class C : public B1, public B2 {public: char x; C(){x='C';};};

int main(){
    C c;
    cout << c.x << endl; // prints C

    cout << c.B1::x << endl; // prints B
    cout << ((B1&) c).x << endl; // prints B

    cout << c.A::x << endl; // normally prints A but doesn't work here
    //cout << ((A&) c).x << endl; // prints A
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wanted to keep every B's A seperate. THX anyways.

Comment: You did not specify that in the question. And may I ask why you want them kept separately?

Comment: Actually you did! I guess I should have been more careful in reading the question.

Comment: Never mind - I could make up an example out of thin air. But the question came up from a theoretical pov.